# GCC typeof extension

Tags: c, gcc, typeof, gcc-extensions

I don't understand why this works:

```
/* gcc range extension */
__extension__ static int fn(int n)
{
    switch (n) {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1 ... 1000: return 1;
        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

But this does not:

```
/* gcc typeof extension */
__extension__ static void fn(int n)
{
    typeof(n) a = n;

    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

gcc returns:

```
demo.c:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘typeof’
demo.c:14: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘typeof’
demo.c:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
demo.c:16: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
demo.c:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
demo.c:16: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

I know I can compile with `-std=gnu99` to avoid the error but the first one works with `-std=c99` and uses also an extension

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Non-ANSI compatible keywords are not ever reenabled by `__extension__` (the only effect of `__extension__` is warning suppression for `-pedantic`). Use `__typeof__` if you want to compile in ANSI mode.

Comment: To anyone looking for more information:  [typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing a header file that must work when included in ISO C programs, write `__typeof__` instead of `typeof`.

Refer to this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords) for a more elaborate description and the possible fixes.

Note:  `__extension__` has no effect aside from suppressing the warnings when using ANSI C `-pedantic` mode.

So something like this:

```
/* gcc typeof extension */
__extension__ static void fn(int n)
{
    __typeof__(n) a = n;

    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```